# What maven dependencies are needed to get service in non osgi project?

Tags: java, maven, osgi

I have a maven nononosgi project witch need to get a service from an osgi project.
Here is my code:

```
BundleContext context = FrameworkUtil.getBundle(this.getClass()).getBundleContext();
ServiceReference serviceReference = context.getServiceReference(MyClass.class.getName()); 
MyClass blah = (MyClass) new ServiceTracker(context, serviceReference, null).getService(); 
blah.doStuff();
```

This ofcourse doesn't work because a lot of classes aren't imported. What dependencies do i need for the code to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can search dependencies at http://search.maven.org based on class names (advanced search).

You need org.osgi:org.osgi.core and org.osgi:org.osgi.compendium. Give the "provided" scope for both of them.